# How do I know if a repair is hung?

Tags: cassandra

I have cluster cassandra-2.2.19-1 with 4 nodes. On one of the nodes, I ran nodetool repair --full, which has been going on for 3 days.

```
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address          Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  192.168.168.2 1003.24 GB  256          71.1%             f0e9a44f-2ae2-45c7-aa8c-6a36a4fc3333  rack1
UN  192.168.168.3  991.04 GB  256          77.4%             f11f037e-d581-4121-a6db-b2cc86a95555  rack1
UN  192.168.168.4  991.04 GB  256          73.9%             5add51ce-0ff5-45b6-9dac-c794962f4444  rack1
UN  192.168.168.5  775.13 GB  256          77.6%             8ca72d79-b747-43da-a7f7-3f3c66a92222  rack1
```

Last log in screen session:

```
[2023-05-13 05:30:40,784] Repair session 8794fdc1-f0c7-11ed-ba39-2b85883cfc23 for range (8596788422948369347,8615166058477064846] finished (progress: 100%)
[2023-05-13 15:56:50,324] Repair completed successfully
[2023-05-13 15:56:50,353] Repair command #1 finished in 20 hours 38 minutes 3 seconds
[2023-05-13 15:56:50,412] Starting repair command #2, repairing keyspace jcr_log with repair options (parallelism: parallel, primary range: false, incremental: false, job threads: 1, ColumnFamilies: [], dataCenters: [], hosts: [], # of ranges: 729)
```

Does this mean the process is hung? In the logs, I do not see fresh entries about repair.
Result of command tpstats:

```
Pool Name                    Active   Pending      Completed   Blocked  All time blocked
MutationStage                     0         0        2036384         0                 0
ReadStage                         0         0        4333434         0                 0
RequestResponseStage              0         0        4961475         0                 0
ReadRepairStage                   0         0         301476         0                 0
CounterMutationStage              0         0              0         0                 0
Repair#2                          1       729              0         0                 0
HintedHandoff                     0         0              4         0                 0
MiscStage                         0         0              0         0                 0
CompactionExecutor                2        66         444705         0                 0
MemtableReclaimMemory             0         0           3341         0                 0
PendingRangeCalculator            0         0              5         0                 0
GossipStage                       0         0        3616095         0                 0
MigrationStage                    0         0              3         0                 0
MemtablePostFlush                 1       107          20818         0                 0
ValidationExecutor                1         1            729         0                 0
Sampler                           0         0              0         0                 0
MemtableFlushWriter               0         0           3342         0                 0
InternalResponseStage             0         0             10         0                 0
AntiEntropyStage                  0         0           3651         0                 0
CacheCleanupExecutor              0         0              0         0                 0
Native-Transport-Requests         0         0        7055933         0                 3

Message type           Dropped
READ                         0
RANGE_SLICE                  0
_TRACE                       0
MUTATION                     0
COUNTER_MUTATION             0
REQUEST_RESPONSE             0
PAGED_RANGE                  0
READ_REPAIR                  0
```

Is it possible to kill this process? Or is there a risk of data loss?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in the details you posted that indicates the process is hung.

These indicate that the repair thread is in progress:

```
Pool Name                    Active   Pending      Completed   Blocked  All time blocked
...
Repair#2                          1       729              0         0                 0
...
ValidationExecutor                1         1            729         0                 0
...
```

You can check the progress of the repair streams with `nodetool netstats`. Additionally, you can also verify if there is an active validation compaction (for repairs) with `nodetool compactionstats`.

I'm not convinced that the repair is hung. You mentioned in [question 327021](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/327021/) that the first repair session took 21 hours. What that indicates to me is that you don't regularly run repairs AND there is a lot of data out-of-sync between replicas which is usually an indication that your cluster gets overloaded so it can't keep up with writes.

Additionally, a regular repair is expensive because it repairs all the token ranges on a node regardless of whether the node is the owner of the token(s). We recommend using a rolling partitioner range repair (with the `-pr` flag), one node at a time, so that token ranges are not repaired repeatedly. For more info, see the blog post [Repairs in Cassandra](https://www.datastax.com/blog/repair-cassandra).

If you're convinced that the repair sessions/threads are hung, you can start over by restarting Cassandra on the nodes which have active repair threads. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, with versions of Cassandra that old, a hung repair is a very real possibility.  A good way to check for that, is to run the following `nodetool` command:

```
nodetool netstats
```

This will give you a summary of the files that have already been sent/received.  The current file being streamed should be giving a running count of the number of its bytes that have been sent.  If you view those counts and they don't seem to be changing, then repair is likely hung.

In that case, it's probably just best to bounce the node.

It is highly recommended to use [Cassandra Reaper](http://cassandra-reaper.io/) to manage your repairs.  This also gives you a better window to their progress, as well as the ability to start and stop them.